# Как называется фильтр, который не позволяет отправлять часть объекта?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Я возвращаю объект из метода в View, мне нужно, чтобы часть полей View не видела, как это делается, кажется видел когда-то давно что можно. Но не могу найти сейчас?

Comment: Может private поля?

Comment: Ну или можно скастить к базовому классу или интерфейсу

Comment: просто создать анонимный тип на основе вашего объекта: `return View(new { myObj.FirstProp, myObj.SecondProp });`

Comment: [DTO](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5)?

Comment: @Bulson, Это не очень удобно делать

Comment: @XelaNimed, вроде этого только у параметра устанавливаешь аннотацию